# Page overflows to right of body

Tags: css, html, width, css-float

I'm incredibly frustrated by this and it would be a tremendous help if someone out there knows how to quickly figure this out...

What's happening is, I'm working on a site that seems to be extending out to the right of the body. In other words, overflowing to the right such that the horizontal scrollbar appears.

You'll see what I mean:
http://www.lahappy.com/blog/

This is killing me! Would really appreciate someone to call out what I may be missing or doing incorrectly.

Thanks-

Comment: Maybe it's a Firefox bug? It calculates `div#content` far too wide, but Chrome comes up with a sane size.

Comment: Try putting `overflow-x:hidden` on the `<html>` element.

Comment: Pascal, it's doing the same in webkit browsers, as well. @Sagar, that works from a visual standpoint, but one can still scroll about 250px to the right. Appreciate you both trying to help... I can't even find anything on the inspector that might be hanging out. Any other fixes you can think of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is within `#fb-root` in the right sidebar. If you remove this element, the layout will fit correctly without a horizontal scroll. The child `iframe` within this element has a width of `575px`. You can change this value to `auto` by setting the style for the iframe in your css as:

```
#fb-root{
    width: auto !important; 
}
```

This line should be placed at the end of the CSS line to overwrite any styles which may disable the `width:auto` style. Ideally, you shouldn't have to use `!important` but since you need to override a FB defined style, I'd try it out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks a ton. You had it spot on, though your suggested fix didn't work, for some strange reason. I did, however, correct it by adding "display: none" to the "FB_UI_Hidden" class. Very strange.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you mind sharing how you discovered this "problem child" so quickly? I tried troubleshooting using inspector and got nowhere - certainly wouldn't have thought to investigate inside the fb iframe nestled that deep...

Comment: Using firebug I deleted different elements to see if that had any effect on the layout. After deleting the FB widget in the inspector, the horizontal scrollbar disappeared. Keeping in mind that FB adds it's own styles and uses iframes, I inspected the `#fb-root` element and found that it set a fixed width on the child `iframe` element.